# Magento setup multidomain with multiple languages

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, ce-1.9.0.1, store-view

I have one store, let's call him default.com and I need to add another 2 domains with different languages,  so I want my store structure to be:

```
default.com -English
           - Spanish

domain.de - German
           - Russian

domain.at - English
           - German
```

domain.de and domain.at will use the same catalog and content that exist in default.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below link to setup multiple domain with different language.

http://www.ecommercegorilla.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-store-fronts-with-magento/

Please let me know if you need any more detail.

Comment: hi, thank you, you setup this for Magento 1.9.1? is work?

Comment: yes it will work on magento 1.9.1. as magento doesn't change domain configuration in magento 1.9.1.